# How to fix "1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm getting up a new server laravel framework, correct the MySQL query to get the data.
Running Laravel 5.6.28, MySql 5.7.21, PHP 7.2.

```
$query = DB::table('Student a')->select([DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS')], 'a.*', b.*')->leftjoin('girls b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.id')->where('a.name', '!=', 'null');

$query->skip($iPagNo)->take($iSwRws);

$sqlPg = $query->get();

print_r($sqlPg);
```

Comment: Use ```dd($query->toSql());``` to echo the generated SQL. Try to run it in PhpMyAdmin or another sql tool for debugging.

Comment: May be a cut/paste problem but you are missing a `'` in `'a.*', b.*')`.

Comment: Still facing the same error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `Student a` left join `girls b` on `a`.`MemberId` = `b' at line 1 (SQL: select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from `Student a` left join `girls b` on `a`.`MemberId` = `b`.`MemberId` "

Comment: You have some form of quote in `Student a\` left` - not sure where that is coming from (I thought it was a spec of dust on my screen at first :-/

Comment: (Not a Laravel person) try the table names without the aliases.

Comment: Tried without giving alias name to the table, but still facing the same error.

Comment: Try to use **whereNotNull('a.name')** instead of where('a.name', '!=', 'null')

Comment: Still facing the error, I think the problem here with "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS". Is this correct way to mention in laravel?

$query = DB::table('Student a')->select([DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS')], 'a.*', 'b.*')->leftjoin('girls b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.id')->where('a.name', '!=', 'null');

Comment: @porkodim have you found the solution?